# How do I write a line of code that could be added to end of showpic function that updates an alt attribute on a placehold element?

Tags: javascript, html, alt

I'm quite new to coding and functions etc.
I've decided to look for online exam papers so I can learn from them questions and one of them says:

> Write a line of code that could be added to the end of the showpic function that updates the alt attribute on the placehold element.

and then there is a long coding which is:

```
window.onload = prepareGallery;

    function prepareGallery() {
        var gallery, links, i;

        if (!document.getElementById) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!document.getElementsByTagName) {
            return false;
        }

        gallery = document.getElementById("images");
        links = gallery.getElementsByTagName("a");

        for(i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            links[i].onclick = function() {
                showPic(this);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    function showPic(pic) {
        var source, placehold, text, desc;

    source = pic.getAttribute("href");
    placehold = document.getElementById("place");
    placehold.setAttribute("src", source);

    text = pic.getAttribute("title");
    desc = document.getElementById("description");
    desc.firstChild.nodeValue = text;
}
```

Comment: Did the solution work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be

```
 pic.setAttribute("alt", "image");
```

Given that the pic argument is a representation of an `<img></img>` tag

**setAttribute** takes two arguments: The first is the tag name (in your case - the alt tag) and the second argument is the value.